# How Do I Import Burst Photos That Aren't Being Recognized By My iMac?

Tags: ios, macos, photos, image-capture

I own a 2007 Macbook running Mac OS X Lion, a 2009 iMac running Mac OS X Yosemite and an iPad Mini 2/iPhone 6 Plus both running iOS 9. None of my burst photos will import using Image Capture or Photos. In fact, Image Capture and Photos don't even recognize them at all. I have over 1,000 images in my camera roll. Over half of them are individual photos that were once part of bursts. Yet, Image Capture and Photos only see around 300 photos in my camera roll, which are photos that were shot individually and were never part of a burst. Even when I go into my burst photos and select each photo within every burst so that they're showing in my camera roll as individual photos, none of them import. How can I import and backup all of my burst photos?

Please Note: This has been an ongoing issue for me ever since burst photos were first introduced.

Unfortunately, the below answer does not answer my question. All of the photos have already been separated from bursts by "selecting" each photo within each burst and also marked as favorites. They are all listed individually in my camera roll. Still, they are not being recognized by Image Capture and Photos. I need to know what to do so that they'll be recognized by Image Capture and Photos so that I can import them. Just to be clear, this is the problem that I am having: All of the photos from bursts are all present in my camera roll as individual photos, but they're not being recognized by Image Capture and Photos on my iMac, so they will not import.

Answer (score 1):

No matter which burst photo,
until it isn't marked as 'Favorite' , it doesn't get to the actual 'Camera Roll'.

So,
Mark those photos as 'Favorite'. Then, try connecting your iOS Device to your Mac. Now, the 'Image Capture' app should open automatically. [If it didn't, check the cable connection(USB<->iOS Device) or manually open the app.
If you're not sure the problem is the wire(cable), see if the iOS device is being charged(of course this happens if you have turned on USB Charging in Settings).]

Also, there's a 3rd-party app named [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)  which can help you in many ways. I recommend this app, but I'm not responsible for any further problems within your Macs or iOS devices.

As the iPhone User Guide (By Apple, available on the iBooks Store for free) suggests:

> Take rapid-fire shots: (iPhone 5s) Touch and hold the shutter button to take photos in burst mode. The counter shows how many shots you’ve taken, until you lift your finger. To see the suggested shots and select the photos you want to keep, tap the thumbnail, then tap “Favorites.” The gray dot(s) mark the suggested photos. To copy a photo from the burst as a separate photo in Camera Roll, tap the circle on the lower-right corner. To delete the burst of photos, tap it, then tap .

Comment: Does this still work?